# Getting NULL value in DateOperator-Projection Aggregate- MongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am using the below code to get the month, week and year from the Date field in the MongoDB collection

```
ProjectionOperation project= project("Id","Date")
                .and(String.valueOf(DateFromString.fromString("Date"))).extractWeek().as("week")
                .and(String.valueOf(DateFromString.fromString("Date"))).extractYear().as("year")
                .and(String.valueOf(DateFromString.fromString("Date"))).extractMonth().as("month");
        GroupOperation group = group("Id","year","month","week").count().as("count");
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(project,group).withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().cursor(new BasicDBObject()).build());
       DBObject result = mMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, collectionName, JSONObject.class).getRawResults();
        System.out.println(result);
```

even tried using the other method

```
ProjectionOperation project= project("Id","Date")
               .and(String.valueOf(DateOperators.Week.weekOf("Date"))).extractWeek().as("week")
               .and(String.valueOf(DateOperators.Year.yearOf("Date"))).extractYear().as("year")
               .and(String.valueOf(DateOperators.Month.monthOf("Date"))).extractMonth().as("month");
               
        GroupOperation group = group("Id","year","month","week").count().as("count");
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(project,group).withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().cursor(new BasicDBObject()).build());
     
        DBObject result = mMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, collectionName, JSONObject.class).getRawResults();
        System.out.println(result);
```

and

```
ProjectionOperation project= project("Id","Date")
               .and(String.valueOf(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromStringOf("Date"))).extractWeek().as("week")
               .and(String.valueOf(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromStringOf("Date"))).extractYear().as("year")
               .and(String.valueOf(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromStringOf("Date"))).extractMonth().as("month");

        GroupOperation group = group("Id","year","month","week").count().as("count");
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(project,group).withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().cursor(new BasicDBObject()).build());

        DBObject result = mMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, collectionName, JSONObject.class).getRawResults();
        System.out.println(result);
```

While printing the result I am getting

```
"year" :  null  , 
"month" :  null  , 
"week" :  null
```

How do I proceed to remove this null and get the actual value?

Comment: What is the type of the `Date` field in the collection?

Comment: type of the `Date` field in the collection: `String`